# Programmatically Modify Android Project with PHP and Rebuild It?

Tags: php, android

Is there a way to programmatically (using PHP or CMD) modify files inside an Android project (e.g. the manifest file, the strings files, replacing the icon, changing class variable values) and then recompile it into a working APK file that can be installed on a phone.

or only modify the .txt file inside raw folder ??

Answer (score 4):

This is possible depending on how and where PHP is installed...

I will give you a scenario for a local installation of PHP on your development computer and using Android Studio.

- Have PHP & Android Studio installed as normal
- Create a batch file that will sign and zip align your APK.
- Edit your project files using any form of file editing, Ajax/php with a website or any other way....
- Run the batch files to compile, sign and zip align the APK file.
- Now PHP has allowed you to edit the project from a webpage, make changes and compile it to a APK.

### This command will compile your project in to a release APK

```
C:\Users\YOURNAME\AndroidStudioProjects\YOURPROJECT\gradlew.bat aR
```

### The following is a windows batch file that will Sign your APK file and then zip align it ready for the play store. - MyRelease.bat

```
set strStorePswd=MyPassword
set strOutputName=MyProject.apk
set strKeyAlias=mykeyalias
set strFileTmp=atempfile.apk
set strOutputFolder=C:\Published\YOURPROJECT
set strKeyStore=C:\Users\YOURNAME\AndroidStudioProjects\YOURPROJECT\MyKeyStore.jks
set strOriginal=C:\Users\YOURNAME\AndroidStudioProjects\YOURPROJECT\YOURPROJECT\build\apk\YOURPROJECT-release-unsigned.apk
set strJavaBinPath=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_10\bin
set strAndroidTools=C:\Program Files\Android\android-studio\sdk\tools

REM Change the above to match your setup 
copy "%strOriginal%" "%strOutputFolder%\%strFileTmp%" /Y >nul
"%strJavaBinPath%\jarsigner.exe" -verbose -sigalg SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore "%strKeyStore%" -storepass "%strStorePswd%" "%strOutputFolder%\%strFileTmp%" %strKeyAlias%
"%strAndroidTools%\zipalign.exe" -f -v 4 "%strOutputFolder%\%strFileTmp%" "%strOutputFolder%\%strOutputName%"

del "%strOutputFolder%\%strFileTmp%"
```

The above batch file will copy your compiled release APK file to **C:\Published\YOURPROJECT\atempfile.apk** and then it will sign it using jarsign. Please note the keystore file location as well... Then it will finally ZipAlign the APK file as and delete the temp / old unzip-aligned file. At this point it should be ready for the play store.

### Edit your project files

Now you should be able to edit your project files with a standard text editing method, this could PHP, note, Ajax or anything at all. You dont need to open Android Studio at all once your project exists correctly.

### Now with PHP

With php you can then run the two following commands, this will compile and ready your APK file for use. PLEASE NOTE, i am not sure if exec will wait until the batch file / compile is complete.

```
exec('C:\Users\YOURNAME\AndroidStudioProjects\YOURPROJECT\gradlew.bat aR');
exec('C:\SOMEPATH\MyRelease.bat');
```

### I have not tested this but it should work - may have errors

The only thing i can really comment also is, check all the "set" variables in the above batch file, Make sure the project file has a gradlew.bat and last but least. Make sure PHP waits for the gradle.bat to run before starting our batch file.

### EDIT - Improved Version

Since answering this question before, I've improved the batch file and done a separate post for batch file and another one. [Easy way to compile, sign, zipalign APK for Android Play Store (Also SHA1 Key Viewer)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21310215/easy-way-to-compile-sign-zipalign-apk-for-android-play-store-also-sha1-key-vi)