# Easy way to compile, sign, zipalign APK for Android Play Store (Also SHA1 Key Viewer)

Tags: android, batch-file, apk, release, sha1

**How do you easily compile and deploy your APK packages to the Google Play Store?**  i have been searching around for the easiest way i could find for my setup and ended up doing the following below? Would you suggest a better way for this?

"Can you sign and zip align your APK file from within Android Studio using a GUI, not by using the terminal?"

### Two Batch Files to assist with your deployment process

The following batch file i created to speed up the testing of my APK files across various devices as i also develop a few person Android to Arudino communications.. So i may need a APK ready after a single change of code/syntax. Anyway... What do they do?

#### Compile, Sign, ZipAlign (Android Studio Version)

- Uses Gradle (Included with Android Studio) to compile your project as a release version
- Copies the release APK from the project folder to a relese folder of your own
- Uses jarsigner to sign the APK file with your KeyStore file
- Uses ZipAlign to create a new copy of the APK ready for google Play Store.
- Deletes the original file that ZipAlign leaves behind

#### complile_release.bat

```
@echo off
REM Modify the variables between the lines to match your installation and project
REM ----------------------------------------------------
set sKeyAlias=MyProjectNameAlias
set sStorePass=MyPassword
set sPathKeyStore=C:\Projects\Android\Key_Stores.keystore
set sFileTmp=igetdeleted.apk
set sFileOutput=MyProjectName.apk
set sPathOrigAPK=C:\Projects\MyProjectFolder\MyProjectName\build\apk\MyProjectName-release-unsigned.apk
set sPathOutput=C:\Projects\Releases
set sPathJavaBin=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_10\bin
set sPathAnTools=C:\Program Files\Android\android-studio\sdk\tools
set sPathGradle=C:\Projects\MyProjectFolder\
set sDriveGradle=%sPathGradle:~0,2% 
REM ----------------------------------------------------


REM -- Navigate to gradlew.bat folder and execute with "aR" for a release version
%sDriveGradle%
cd %sPathGradle%
call "gradlew.bat" aR

REM -- Copy the compiled APK to our output/release folder
copy "%sPathOrigAPK%" "%sPathOutput%\%sFileTmp%" /Y >nul

REM -- Sign the APK package
"%sPathJavaBin%\jarsigner.exe" -verbose -sigalg SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore "%sPathKeyStore%" -storepass "%sStorePass%" "%sPathOutput%\%sFileTmp%" %sKeyAlias%

REM -- Zipalign the APK package (This creates a copy)
"%sPathAnTools%\zipalign.exe" -f -v 4 "%sPathOutput%\%sFileTmp%" "%sPathOutput%\%sFileOutput%"

REM -- Delete the original from the zipalign output the APK package
del "%sPathOutput%\%sFileTmp%"

REM -- Awaiting user input before closing the window
pause
```

---

#### Viewing APK SHA1 Value

The following batch file with simply let you view the SHA1 key or other details as you need

#### view_sha1.bat

```
@echo off

REM Modify the variables between the lines to match your installation and project
REM ----------------------------------------------------
set sKeyAlias=MyProjectNameAlias
set sStorePass=MyPassword
set sPathJavaBin=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_10\bin
set sPathKeyStore=C:\Projects\Android\Key_Stores.keystore
REM ----------------------------------------------------

REM -- This will use the Java keytool to display the some information about the APK including the SHA1 key as required for google
"%sPathJavaBin%\keytool" -list -v -keystore "%sPathKeyStore%" -storepass "%sStorePass%" -alias "%sKeyAlias%"

REM -- Awaiting user input before closing the window
pause
```

I hope these two can be of some help / use to people

Comment: StackOverflow is for questions. What is your question?

Comment: The question is if this is a correct or a preferred way to compile your project while also offering the code for people to use.

Comment: Editing with top comment/question. When reading about posting questions on a StackExchange, it was advise you are encouraged to ask and answer your own questions as this is a good way to share knowledge... So i did... http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/

Comment: You may wish to read the StackOverflow documentation and follow the instructions for doing this properly: http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Comment: That link you provided should be easily accessible from the http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask as i can not a see a direct link from the ask page.